# Integer type property not changing when value is changed in UWP app with Template 10 validation

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp, mvvm-light, template10

Thanks for visiting.

I am trying to validate a textbox bound to an integer type property using Template 10 validation in a UWP app but the set accessor does not fire when the data is a character, only when it is an integer. Everything works fine when I use a string type property. I am using MVVM light.

Here is my model:

```
public class User : ValidatableModelBase
{
    public User()
    {
    }

    public string FirstName
    {
        get
        {
            return Read<string>();
        }
        set
        {
            Write(value);
        }
    }
    public string LastName
    {
        get
        {
            return Read<string>();
        }
        set
        {
            Write(value);
        }
    }

    public int ID
    {
        get
        {
            return Read<int>();
        }
        set
        {
            Write(value);
        }
    }



    public override string ToString() => $"{FirstName} {LastName}";
}
```

Here is my class that returns some sample data and also specifies the validation logic:

```
public static class UserService
{
    public static User GetUser()
    {
        var user = new User
        {
            Validator = i =>
            {
                var u = i as User;
                if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(u.FirstName))
                {
                    u.Properties[nameof(u.FirstName)].Errors.Add("First name is required");
                }
                if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(u.LastName))
                {
                    u.Properties[nameof(u.LastName)].Errors.Add("Last name is required");
                }
                int x;
                if (!int.TryParse(u.ID.ToString(), out x))
                {
                    u.Properties[nameof(u.ID)].Errors.Add("Integers only allowed");
                }

            }
        };

        return user;
    }
}
```

Here is my ViewModel:

```
public class BlankViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    public RelayCommand ValidateCommand { get; private set; }
    public BlankViewModel()
    {
             ValidateCommand = new RelayCommand(ValidateCommandAction);
    }

    private void ValidateCommandAction()
    {
        //Do something
    }

    private async Task<User> GetUser()
    {
        return await Task.Run(() => UserService.GetUser()).ConfigureAwait(false);
    }

    User _selected;
    public Models.User Selected
    {
        get
        {
            _selected = GetUser().Result;
            return _selected;
        }
        set
        {
            try
            {
                Set(ref _selected, value);
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {


            }

        }
    }

}
```

Here is the view:

```
<Grid 
        Grid.Row="1" 
        Background="{ThemeResource SystemControlPageBackgroundChromeLowBrush}">
        <!--The SystemControlPageBackgroundChromeLowBrush background represents where you should place your content. 
            Place your content here.-->
        <StackPanel DataContext="{Binding Selected}">
            <validate:ControlWrapper PropertyName="FirstName">
                <TextBox Text="{Binding FirstName, Mode=TwoWay}" Header="First Name"/>
            </validate:ControlWrapper>
            <validate:ControlWrapper PropertyName="LastName">
                <TextBox Text="{Binding LastName,Mode=TwoWay,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Header="Last Name"/>
            </validate:ControlWrapper>
            <validate:ControlWrapper PropertyName="ID">
                <TextBox Text="{Binding ID,Mode=TwoWay,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Header="ID"/>
            </validate:ControlWrapper>
            <Button Content="Validate" IsEnabled="{Binding IsValid}"/>
        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
```

Everything works fine for the firstname and lastname properties but the ID property validation logic and the set accessor don't fire when the property is set to a character, only when it is an integer and not even when it is a double.

I would really appreciate some help. Thanks a lot in advance.

Answer (score 1):

It should be the issue of the `ValidatableModelBase` class in the `Template10.Validation`.

As the [Introducing Template10 Validation](https://github.com/Windows-XAML/Template10.Validation),

> If you have feedback or a bug to report, do it here: https://github.com/Windows-XAML/Template10/issues.

You can report this issue in the above link.

Currently, you can change your **int** ID property to **string** type, then change your `GetUser` static method to the following code, it will work well as your requirement.

```
public static User GetUser()
{
    var user = new User
    {
        Validator = i =>
        {
            var u = i as User;
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(u.FirstName))
            {
                u.Properties[nameof(u.FirstName)].Errors.Add("First name is required");
            }
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(u.LastName))
            {
                u.Properties[nameof(u.LastName)].Errors.Add("Last name is required");
            }
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(u.ID))
            {
                u.Properties[nameof(u.ID)].Errors.Add("Integers is required");
            }
            else
            {
                int x;
                bool success = int.TryParse(u.ID.ToString(), out x);
                if (!success)
                {
                    u.Properties[nameof(u.ID)].Errors.Add("Integers only allowed");
                }
            }
        }
    };
    return user;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your response! Unfortunately, I can't change the data type of the property because it will break the application I am working on. This was just a sample I made for this question only. I do appreciate your response. I solved the problem by by making a string property that wraps around the problem integer property and it works fine.

Comment: @VivekVerma Okay, Wrapping the int property with a string property is also a better solution. I can only see this sample and provide a solution for the sample. I am glad to hear your solution too. You could share your solution as an answer to convenient other people who visit this thread later.